# input type='file' not working in instagram in-app browser

Tags: ios, html, web, instagram, inappbrowser

When you try to upload a file using input type='file' on a webpage that is opened in the instagram in-app browser, the page just reloads. In facebook in-app browser there is no such problem.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: When we opened our site in-app browser, and try to upload file by using input, page just has reloading. How we can fix this issue on client side?

Comment: @OleksiiLyhun - Were you able to resolve the issue? I am also facing the same issue on Facebook app browser. Please advice if you find any solution. Thanks

Comment: @AwaisImran No, I didn't find a solution

Comment: @OleksiiLyhun Sad to know that :( Thanks anyways.

Comment: There's no solution for this. I've submitted a bug report to instagram. I also independently tested giphy.com, tinypic.com, and even logged in to facebook in the instagram in-app browser and can confirm every single site that uses photo uploads refreshes in instagrams in-app browser. No photo uploads work in instagram, which sucks...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this will still be useful to somebody, I had a similar problem, except in my case when I clicked on a "choose file" button nothing happened at all. I fixed it by changing the `accept` attribute of the button to contain only mime types and not extensions.

So this:

```html
<input
  type="file"
  accept=".jpg,.png,.svg"
/>
```

Should be replaced by this:

```html
<input
  type="file"
  accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/svg+xml"
/>
```

This is very confusing because the first version works in all other browsers and docs at MDN also mention that it is correct.